# Unable to determine the status of "Catching up" node

Tags: stellar-core, nodes

My stellar-core node is not syncing past 1/2 children completed. In my config, I have:

```
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false
CATCHUP_RECENT=1024
```

When I call "info" I see this:

```json
"info" : {
   "build" : "stellar-core 12.4.0 (c47415d4cd2b313a6f89fcb5ee7de46feb4673a1)",
   "history_failure_rate" : "0",
   "ledger" : {
      "age" : 136255460,
      "baseFee" : 100,
      "baseReserve" : 100000000,
      "closeTime" : 1447453858,
      "hash" : "4de7af86e0e14bb5ced248d14d5dc48593aa52505dfff95f9f9f10d114327304",
      "maxTxSetSize" : 50,
      "num" : 766079,
      "version" : 1
   },
   "network" : "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015",
   "peers" : {
      "authenticated_count" : 8,
      "pending_count" : 0
   },
   "protocol_version" : 12,
   "quorum" : {
      "node" : "GCGSQ",
      "qset" : {
         "agree" : 20,
         "delayed" : 0,
         "disagree" : 0,
         "fail_at" : 4,
         "hash" : "44cedc",
         "ledger" : 28589076,
         "missing" : 0,
         "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE"
      },
      "transitive" : {
         "critical" : null,
         "intersection" : true,
         "last_check_ledger" : 28589010,
         "node_count" : 24
      }
   },
   "startedOn" : "2020-03-08T23:09:49Z",
   "state" : "Catching up",
   "status" : [ "Catching up: Running: catchup : 1/2 children completed" ]
}
```

This has been the case for several hours. I don't see any progress being made in the log or any attempt to "catch up". I'm seeing new ledgers come in that correspond with the latest ledgers on stellar.expert but then it always just reports "catching up 1/2 children completed".

```
2020-03-08T23:15:47.027 GCGSQ [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 28589081 : {"agree":20,"delayed":0,"disagree":0,"fail_at":4,"hash":"44cedc","ledger":28589081,"missing":0,"phase    ":"EXTERNALIZE"}

2020-03-08T23:15:47.033 GCGSQ [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=28589083, prev=f2d530, txs=112, ops=189, sv: [ txH: e30aa0, ct: 1583709346, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2020-03-08T23:15:47.033 GCGSQ [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=28589083, prev=f2d530, txs=112, ops=189, sv: [ txH: e30aa0, ct: 1583709346, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2020-03-08T23:15:47.033 GCGSQ [Ledger INFO] Close of ledger 28589083 buffered
2020-03-08T23:15:47.033 GCGSQ [Ledger INFO] Close of ledger 28589083 buffered
2020-03-08T23:15:47.033 GCGSQ [History INFO] Catching up: Waiting: catchup : 1/2 children completed
```

What is the missing 2/2 "step" for Catchup? How can I tell if it's working or not working? How can I get a % status on the catchup process? It doesn't appear as if anything is going wrong and there are no errors in the logs, but I'm just waiting and getting new ledgers as they come in but perpetually sitting at "Catching up" instead of "Synced".

Comment: No idea, could be anything. But some general quick advice: increase your peers + restart. `TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS=16`

The status % is round about  (100 / 28599626 * info.ledger.num) where the magic number 28599626 is the current ledger which can be found here https://horizon.stellar.org/